# How would you get the names of the methods of a type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm building a wrapper to convert a callback syntax function into async/await like so:

```js
function operation<D, M extends keyof D>(
    obj: D,
    methodName: M,
    ...args: Parameters<D[M]>
): Promise<ReturnType<D[M]>> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return obj[methodName](...args, (err, result) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(result));
    });
}
```

This works, but the issue is that the parameters I can pass into `methodName` not only include the names of the methods of `D` but also the properties (i.e. variable properties). Is there any way I can have it so `F` can only be a property of `D` that is of type `Function`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the keys of an object that reference functions with something like:

```
type MethodNames<T extends { [K in keyof T]: any }> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends Function // is this key a function?
      ? K // yes, return the key
      : never // no, return never
}[keyof T] // get union of all values (which are now the keys) that are not never

interface A {
  value: string
  fn1(): void
  fn2(): void
}

type B = MethodNames<A> // "fn1" | "fn2"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=41#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAcgQwLYQM4B4AVKCAD2AgDsVcoBvKAbQGkoBLSqAawhCQDMohALoAuKBkogoAXwB8UALz0AsACgoTVh268BQses2bCLYSXJUaUAGIBXSgGNgbJJwD079rURtaPaQwofgdnV0oAfiNjTQioVk8oEDwAGigAJ3g7dM5EaADomPFKCAA3CHSoRMokNMzgbM4S8vT1GUYA-REqrwBzeCgHcKh9DAAbMahS8bs8KAAKAHcENkcECUyoGsWoPN0QXABKXYQMYA3oGvPmivV1Dgp0-gxHaABBVQ0pmYhxXGB0hxetF+JQAIzzQ7iUpINgoEGUABMkOhsPhahkdzUoEgUAAQkpYPBkOhsHh8G8FIkAESgsHUqAAHygtKR1KAA)

You should now be able to declare the generic parameter for the method name `M` using this helper:

```
M extends MethodNames<D>
```

Now typescript will ensure that `M` is a key of `D` that a type of `Function`.